# Handle no internet with urllib.request

Tags: python, json, urllib

I have a program that handles **JSON data by doing a JSON API request** using **urllib.request** , the program **crashes when the internet disconnects** , i want it to keep trying so when the **internet comes back it keeps on doing the request**

---

```
def data_parser(currency,coin):
    req = urllib.request.Request(url)
    r=urllib.request.urlopen(req).read()
    cont = json.loads(r.decode('utf-8'))
    kota = float(cont['prices'][currency][coin])
    pprint(cont['prices'][currency][coin])
    return kota

def main():
    period = 10
    par_1 = sys.argv[1]
    par_2 = sys.argv[2]
    while True:
        print("----")
        price_1=data_parser(par_1,par_2)
        if price_1 > 5.00:
            winsound.Beep(f,d);
        time.sleep(period)
```

Comment: i don't want the program to crash when the internet disconnects

Comment: my question is how can i handle that particular scenario ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a `try-except` block.

**Ex:**

```
def data_parser(currency,coin):
    try:
        req = urllib.request.Request(url)
        r=urllib.request.urlopen(req).read()
        cont = json.loads(r.decode('utf-8'))
        kota = float(cont['prices'][currency][coin])
        pprint(cont['prices'][currency][coin])
        return kota
    except Exception as err:                   
        return data_parser(currency,coin)
```

Comment: Thanks its working

Comment: You are welcome :)